# TListbox - OnChangeEvent does not fire reliable on multiselect

Tags: delphi, onchange, firemonkey, multi-select, tlistbox

I'm using XE7 and FMX.

My problem is that the OnChange-Event for TListbox works not correctly with multiselect (it does not fire everytime when a change occured).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a FMX-application and add a TListbox to his form.
- Add items to this listbox.
- Set 'MultiSelectStyle' of Listbox to 'default'.
- Handle the OnChangeEvent (set a breakpoint or do something ...).
- Now run the project and click on the first Item -> OnChange is executed.
- But if first item is **clicked again** the OnChange will **not** be **executed**.

Can tell me somebody how I can fix this, so that everytime when a the selection changes I get a event.

Comment: use onClick event to handle this. Selected item is not changed when it clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation [FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.OnChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.OnChange):

> Occurs when the selection in the list box changes.
>   Write an OnChange event handler to take specific action immediately after a new item or items are selected in the list box.

Use the `OnClick` or `OnItemClick` event instead to monitor when the user reselects the same selection. And keep the `OnChange` handler for all new selections.

Comment: OnClick fires only if item is selected with mouse and does not fire when item is selected with keyboard.

Comment: @Rynardald, you will use onClick event to handle selected item is clicked again. for others you will use onChange